# React native.- Using setState doesnt change props in textInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use a text input to filter a ViewList but it seems like because the initial state of 'text' is "", it always loops in a way everytime a type something it goes back to "" deleting everything a type

The filter function goes

```js
filterSearch (texto) {

  const newData = this.Data.filter((item) => {
    const itemData = item.nombre.toUpperCase()
    const textData = this.texto.toUpperCase()
    return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
  })

  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newData),
    text: texto 
  })
}
```

and is called from a textInput

```js
<TextInput 
  style={styles.busqueda}
  placeholder= 'Buscar'
  onChangeText={(text) => this.filterSearch.bind(text)}
  value={this.state.text}
>
</TextInput>
```

it seems like filterSearch isnt being called the right way...

Comment: You're passing a function to **onChangeText** property of the TextInput that returns another (bound) function with **this** propery set to **text**. You want to set **onChangedText** to something like `this.filterSearch.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 changes you need to do:

1/ *Use the correct syntax to execute your function*:

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.filterSearch(text)}
```

Actually, the `onChangeText` function was lexical bound to the component already (by using `() => {}`)

2/ *You also need to bind the `filterSearch` function* to the react component too, then you can use `this` inside it (by either way below):

a) Using lexical binding:

```
filterSearch = (texto) => {
  //...
}
```

b) Bind the function in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // ...
  this.filterSearch = this.filterSearch.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you had it working, if so, please consider an upvote as well as accept my answer. For further issues, please just post here, we will try to find solution together, thanks ^*

Answer (score 0):

`onChangeText={(text) => this.filterSearch(text)}`

or

`onChangeText={this.filterSearch.bind(this)}`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.